# How to access numpy array passed through Cython

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, cython

I am trying to understand which is the **fastest** and **safest** way to access a NumPy array passed through Cython to a C code.
I have the following files:

**func.c:**

```
typedef struct {
    int nr;                
    double *my_array;      
} my_struct;

my_struct grid;

void allocate(int n) {
    grid.nr = n;
    grid.my_array = (double*)malloc(grid.nr*sizeof(double));
}

void Cfunc1(double *array) {
    my_array = array;

    //e.g. operation on my_array..
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) my_array[i] *= 0.1;
}

void Cfunc2(int n, double *array) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        my_array[i] = array[i];

    //e.g. operation on my_array..
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) my_array[i] *= 0.1;

}
```

**func_wrap.pyx:**

```
cdef extern from "func.h":
    void myfunc1(double *)
    void myfunc2(int, double *) 
    void allocate(int)

def pyfunc1(int n, double[:] array):
    allocate(n)
    Cfunc1(&array[0])

def pyfunc2(int n, double[:] array):
    allocate(n)
    Cfunc2(n, &array[0])
```

**setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import distutils
setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}, ext_modules = [Extension("func", ["func.c"])])
```

**func.so** is produced with:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

**py_func.py:**

```
import numpy
import func

arr = numpy.random.randn(10)
func.pyfunc1(arr)   # or func.pyfunc2(len(arr), arr)
```

Some questions:

1. Is it faster to use `Cfunc1()` or `Cfunc2()`?
2. Using `Cfunc2` implies that data are copied? Which one would you use?
3. Theoretically, I would have said that `Cfunc1` does not require a previous `malloc` of `my_array`, whereas `Cfunc2` should require it. Instead, both the functions seem to work without `malloc`could you tell me why?

Many thanks!

Comment: 1) You tell me! `timeit` is your friend... 2) That depends on what `pyfunc` does (do you need to modify `array`? do you want do modify it in place?) 3) Could you show us where you declare `my_array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question boils down to "do I need to copy the content of an array when I pass the array to C code". The answer is no you do not, but in some cases you might want to. Mainly when you want to modify the content somehow without disrupting the original array. Also in some cases it might be useful to copy an non-contigious array to a contiguous array before you run a computationally intensive algorithm on the data. That being said, your current code assumes the data is already contiguous so in the non-contiguous case it would just give the wrong result, copy or no copy.

If you're going to use pointer access to numpy arrays, you almost always want to use `double[::1]` instead of `double[:]` so that cython inserts an error checking step to make sure the array is contiguous.

Also if you're going to copy the content of a numpy array into some other data structure, (ie a c array or a malloc memory block) you need to declare/allocate enough memory in order to do that. Without seeing how my_array is declared and assigned, there is no way to know how your code works, but the memory has to be allocated somewhere.

Comment: I have previously allocated my_array with my_array = (double*)malloc((n)*sizeof(double)). my_array belongs to a globally defined structure, but I didn't want to add this detail in order to keep the question more general. Let's say that I have many of my_array, some of them will be used just read-only in C, whereas others will be used to return values to the Python script. Should I adopt a different behaviour for them?

Comment: @mtazzari, You need to be more specific. Without knowing more what you're trying to achieve, it's hard make any recommendations.